# Changing languages in Assassin's Creed: BH

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-brotherhood

By default, the game is in Russian on my game console; however, I was able to do some hacking in menu and now the characters speak English, but the menu and text is still in Russian.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by creating new account and than switching languages and restarting the game(it doesn't change right away). The sad thing is that it has inherited the language from old AC2 game(there I didn't even try to fight it, because i already knew the game)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I haven't faced the same problem I can only give suggestions.

Let me know if this works:

> Start menu -> Run  Type regedit  Go to
>   the folder
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\ubisoft\Assassin's
>   creed II  There's a value named
>   Language, double click it and type
>   English.

Comment: I forgot to add that its under xbox360(because I thought its the same for ps3 and I forgot about PC). thx fo answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Although I had the language set to english everywhere, it seems the game uses the system locale for the language in the menus.

The solution was to go to `My XBox -> System Settings -> Console Settings -> Language and Locale` and choose an english-speaking country for your locale. (Only changing the language did nothing in my case).